# Getting Background color to always just wrap about text using css

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I currently have this:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
`<li>
   <a href="#companyprofile">
      <img class="ui-li-thumb picture" src="img/album-bb.jpg">  
      <h3>Acura</h3>
      <p>Rating: <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span> 
      <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span></p>
      <p class = "open">open</p>
      <p style="background-color:blue !important;">Fixes Geysers</p>
  </a></li`>
```

Now my problem is that the blue for the fix geysers goes to the end of the li tag. Now To fix this is simple. I just set a width:7em to the p tag. BUT I would like to know is, is their a way to now specify the width and always just have the background color wrap around the text? My reason being for this is the services I will be pulling from a database and the text length will vary. I just want to have the blue wrap the text. I'm not sure how to dynamically do this based on the text.

Comment: Use a `span` instead of a `p` and you shouldn't need to use a width at all.

Comment: Aaaaaaaa Touche! Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<span style="background-color:blue !important;">Fixes Geysers</span>
```

and after that you can apply whatever you want on the span :) it's the `<p>` that causes you this problem

Answer (score 0):

A CSS file is preferred over inline CSS, but if you change the last paragraph to display:inline-block then it should shrink the width to the content.

```
  <li>
     <a href="#companyprofile">
        <img class="ui-li-thumb picture" src="img/album-bb.jpg">  
        <h3>Acura</h3>
        <p>Rating: <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span> 
        <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-star fa-1x" style="color:yellow"></span></p>
        <p class = "open">open</p>
        <p style="background-color:blue !important; display: inline-block">Fixes Geysers</p>
    </a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 solutions.

Wrap the text inside a span and give the background color to it :

```
<p><span style="background-color:blue !important;">Fixes Geysers</span></p>
```

Or add `display : inline-block` to the `p` (but it may change you layout) :

```
<p style="background-color:blue !important; display : inline-block;">Fixes Geysers</p>
```

See it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/pDpSq/